# many dd-wrt compatible routers not listed in official table of hardware?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

Sorry, newbie question -

I see a lot of routers where the manufacturer or a reviewer claims dd-wrt compatibility, such as [here](http://www.pcmag.com/roundup/351724/the-best-wireless-routers-that-can-run-dd-wrt), but they are absent from the [official dd-wrt table of hardware page](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start).

Can I assume the reviews are correct, and the hardware list is out of date / poorly maintained?

Comment: The list is actually correct.  DD-WRT is open source which means anyone can build it for any particular router. I have no idea what the requirements are to get a router on the list

Comment: That's hard to square with the manufacturer's claims. Unless maybe these unlisted routers come with dd-wrt already installed? But then I'd have to trust them, which kind of takes away part of the reason to use dd-wrt in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand the question?  The list is accurate but itso doesn't list every compatible router that exists, because DD-WRT and it can be built for any router with even knowledge to do so.

Comment: I suppose I should back up and ask another question, which is how one installs dd-wrt on a router that claims compatibility, but is not on the official list. All the tutorials / instructions I've found tell me to go through the dd-wrt site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your link for the "table of hardware page" is for OpenWrt,
which is not the same as DD-WRT. You should be checking in the
[DD-WRT Router Database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).
Devices listed in the table will have links to the firmware,
but you should still check how good and complete are the listed ports.

For example, taking the first router in the article, the Asus RT-AC88U,

This router does not exist in the Router Database, so I next
searched in the list of
[DD-WRT Supported Devices](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices),
where indeed it appears as a supported device.

To find the firmware, I next entered the
[DD-WRT Forum](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/)
and used the Search for "Asus RT-AC88U" (all terms).
This found the pretty recent thread for the
[Asus RT-AC88U AC3100](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=288784&start=0).

The thread contains some links to beta versions from
[01-02-2016](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2016/01-02-2016-r28647/asus-rt-ac88u/) and [01-13-2016](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2016/01-13-2016-r28788/asus-rt-ac88u/), but the last entries in the thread don't sound
very encouraging and still mention serious and unsolved problems.

The conclusion is that this router only has beta versions of DD-WRT,
which are in addition not very recent or dependable or fully functioning,
so any claim for full DD-WRT compatibility is false.

I suggest that you should only believe in routers which are found in the
Router Database, and then still verify further that the listed DD-WRT version
is not a beta version, and then check again what is said in the Forum about
the port to this router. Verify also the installation procedure,
because for some routers some serious hardware hacking is required 
(for example soldering).

If you decide to port to DD-WRT, ensure first
that you have the installation media for the router's original firmware
from the manufacturer, and also that you master the know how,
or have the tools, to force its installation in a bricked router,
just in case.